# Android: Why is layout_marginTop only working with include tag?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following template in my android app. When I use  the android:layout_MarginTop="20dip" does work well, i can see the 20dip space at the top of the layout.

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
style="@style/list_buttom_single"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/image" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />
<LinearLayout android:gravity="center_vertical" android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1.0">
    <TextView android:text="Login / Register" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/title" style="@style/content_page_large_text" />
    <TextView android:text="sample text" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/subtitle" android:visibility="visible" style="@style/content_page_small_text" />
</LinearLayout>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/itemCount" android:visibility="gone" style="@style/content_page_large_count_text" />
<ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/chevron" style="@style/list_buttom_chevron" />
</LinearLayout>
```

However, when I try to do this programatically using LayoutInflater, i am loosing this 20dip space.

```
        View notesView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_single, null);
    ((TextView) notesView.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText("Notes");
    ((TextView) notesView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle)).setText("102 notes");
    btnContainer.addView(notesView);
```

Why am I getting two different behavior for the "same" action, the only difference is that one is include uisng xml and the other one is using java.

Many thanks
T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because layout parameters are only associated with view if you specify parent view. That's why you should use another version of [`inflate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean%29):

```
View notesView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_single, btnContainer, false);
...
btnContainer.addView(notesView);
```